# Spring Boot 3.2.x + Gradle + `bootBuildImage` + bitbucket-pipelines = `Docker API 'localhost:2375/v1.24/containers/create' failed 403 "Forbidden"`

Tags: spring-boot, bitbucket-pipelines

I've stripped down bitbucket-pipeslines.yml to a minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```yaml
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build
        image: gradle:8.7-jdk21
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - gradle bootBuildImage
```

this results in the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
> Docker API call to 'localhost:2375/v1.24/containers/create' failed with status code 403 "Forbidden"
```

If I add an extra pipeline step, per recommendations: `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.17.0.1:2375` I get the similar error:

```
Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
> Docker API call to '172.17.0.1:2375/v1.24/containers/create' failed with status code 403 "Forbidden"
```

I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.4 which is the latest as of this writing. My project is mostly what is auto-generated by https://start.spring.io/

btw, on my local laptop, `gradle bootBuildImage` works fine, but in the bitbucket-pipelines environment, it is failing as discussed.

I was expecting the image building to work.

Comment: You define the docker host ``` 172.17.0.1``` , so where is  this ip ,  is that accessable for your deploy  environment ? and make sure that the docker daemon is in root or correct permission  .You can try running ls -l /var/run/docker.sock to check the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely to be running into the problems documented in this Spring Boot issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28387.

As shown there, a configuration similar to this is required to work around limitations of the BitBucket Docker configuration:

```
tasks.named('bootBuildImage') {
    docker {
        host = "tcp://172.17.0.1:2375"
        bindHostToBuilder = true
        buildWorkspace {
            bind {
                source = "/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build/cache-${project.name}.work"
            }
        }
        buildCache {
            bind {
                source = "/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build/cache-${project.name}.build"
            }
        }
        launchCache {
            bind {
                source = "/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build/cache-${project.name}.launch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```